# Question about basis changing (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I have a question about basis changing and the matrix associated with it. A book I am following has the following example:
Find the matrix associated with the change of basis from $E = \{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$ (the usual base) to $S = \{(1, 0, 1), (2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2)\} $.

The author goes on by explaining that the answer is the matrix
$$M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I disagree with that assertion and I have the impression that this matrix actually corresponds to the converse change (ie. from $S$ to $E$).

For example, say that we have $[x]_S = (1, 0, 0)^T$. That means that we are having a unit of the $i$ that corresponds to $S$ and therefore the vector in $E$ would be $[x]_E = (1, 0, 1)^T$. We can verify this by verifying that by multiplying $[x]_E = M \circ [x]_S$. This kinda justifies that $M$ actually translates vectors from $S$ to $E$, in contrast to the author who states that's the converse.

What am I missing? Thanks!

**Optional Note**

A simpler example to further illustrate the way I am approaching the concept is the change of basis from $A = \{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ to $B = \{(2, 0), (0, 2)\}$, which basically stretches both the standard vectors by $2$.

Say, on the coordinates of $B$, we have that $i_B = 3$ and $j_B = 2$. That is, we have $[x]_B = (3, 2)$. This means that, on the standard coordinates, both $i$ and $j$ are half the coordinates of $B$, therefore, in order to find the coords of our example on our standard language, we should multiply both the coordinates by a factor of $2$. So, we have $[x]_A = (6, 4)$.

This can be done exactly by the matrix:
$$M^B_A =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and the converse is:
$$(M^B_A)^{-1} = M^A_B =
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$, which follows my reasoning as on the above example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are perfectly right, and indeed the *coordinate transformation* $[x]_E\mapsto [x]_S$ is given by $M^{-1}$.

However, here it seems basis transformation means (the linear extension of) the map $e_i\mapsto s_i$, and that is simply $M$, coordinated in the basis $E$.